ModuleNotFoundError: No module named. In github actions by using pytest
I have the following structure in github repository:
homework_6
├── pr3
│   ├── project
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   │   ├── model.py
│   │   └── processing.py
│   ├── report_model.html
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── model
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── test_model.py



homework_9
├── pr1
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── project
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   │   └── utils.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── model
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── test_streamlit.py
└── pr2
    ├── README.md
    ├── project
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── main.py
    │   └── utils.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        └── model
            ├── __init__.py
            └── test_gradio.py

When I run test by using github actions, all the tests from homework_6 are collected and work without errors, but when the tests from homework_9 fail with the following error messages:
ERROR collecting homework_9/pr1/tests/model/test_streamlit.py _________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/runner/work/machine_learning_in_production/machine_learning_in_production/homework_9/pr1/tests/model/test_streamlit.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.10/x64/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.model.test_streamlit'

And I don't understand why (especially when tests from homework_6 run without problem).
Here is my github action file:
name: ci

on:
  push: 
  pull_request:

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v5
      with:
        python-version: '3.11'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r main_requirements.txt
    - name: Run tests
      run: pytest -v --tb=long

And locally everything works without any error.

This question is similar to: pytest cannot import module while python can. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  (Found using this)
